# Canvas: How do I rotate angle of shape with Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I'm trying to make a pinball game and wondering the logic of the pinball flipper motion.

On the even handler of a right arrow, I want to move my rectangular piece several degrees up.

```
ctx.rotate(-(20*Math.PI/180));
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.rposX , this.rposY, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
    if (rPressed) {
      this.flipRight(ctx);
}
```

Is what I have. How should I try to flip the flipper. Sometimes, I rotate it but that rotates all the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Rotating a rendering

To do the flippers you create a function that draws a flipper at the origin (0,0) and along the xAxis left to right.

So from your rectangle example rather than draw the rectangle where the flipper is, draw it so that the canvas coords 0,0 is at the point of rotation. You will move it via the transform to the correct position.

```
ctx.strokeRect(-10,-10,100,20); // 0,0 is point of rotation
```

You position the flipper by moving its center point `setTransform` I use setTransform as it save having to use save and restore.

```
// x,y is the position you want the flipper to be.
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y); // sets position of flipper by moving point of rotation
```

And then rotate with

```
ctx.rotate(angle); // angle is in radians
```

The just draw the flipper

```
ctx.strokeRect(-10,-10,100,20); // 0,0 is point of rotation
```

#### Keyboard events

To animate I draw the flippers 60 times a second. I have two event listeners listen to `keydown` and `keyup` events. When a key is down I set the flipper flag on to true and when key up to false. I don't do any other processing in the key events.

See demo for more details on key event listeners

#### Animating the flippers

In the animation loop I call the flipper update function. It checks if the flipper is on or off and then moves the flipper depending on its state. This function is called once for every animation frame.

#### Example

I have not done a flipper or pinball game in a long time so I had a bit of fun and created some working flippers.

The function you want is called drawFlipper it has comments. The whole lot is animated using requestAnimationFrame

```js
// get the canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// defines the flipper
const flipper = {
  on : false,  // on when key down
  size : 20,  // radius of flipper base
  pos : 0.1,  
  shapeAng : Math.PI * 0.4, // approx angle to pointy end that line starts at the big arc
  point : 5,  // radius of pointy end
  length : 100, // length of flipper
  action : 0, // action is the rotational position 
  actionDest : 0, // is current destination where flipper should be
  actionV : 0.0, // is movement towards destination
  // next two numbers v must be 0 < v < 1
  actionAccel : 0.7, // relative acceleration of flipper for action. bigger number faster flipper
  actionDrag : 0.61, // amount of drag on flipper action. Smaller number more drag
  actionExtent : 1, // max travel of flipper
  actionBumperDamp : 0.8, // Amount of dampening flipper stop has
  update(){
     if(this.on){
        this.actionDest = this.actionExtent;
     }else{
          this.actionDest = 0; // home position
     }
     this.actionV += (this.actionDest - this.action) * this.actionAccel;
     this.actionV *= this.actionDrag
     this.action += this.actionV
     if(this.action > this.actionExtent){
         this.action = this.actionExtent;
         this.actionV *= this.actionBumperDamp;
         this.actionV -= this.actionV;
     }
  }
}

// keyboard listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{ 
     flipper.actionDrag = Number(dragIn.value);
     flipper.actionAccel = Number(accelIn.value);
     flipper.on = true
});
document.addEventListener("keyup",(e)=>{ flipper.on = false});
window.focus(); // get the keyboards attention

// draws a flipper
// x,y is the location of the flipper base
// start angle is the home angle of the flipper
// flipperTravelDirection is flipper travel direction when active

function drawFlipper(x,y,startAng,flipperTravelDirection){
  // set the position
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
  // set the angle of the flipper plus action position
  ctx.rotate(startAng + flipper.action * flipperTravelDirection);
  // draw the flipper. the transform sets position and rotation
  // so just have to render the flipper around its own center 0,0
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, flipper.size,flipper.shapeAng, Math.PI * 2 - flipper.shapeAng);
  ctx.lineTo(flipper.length, - flipper.point);
  ctx.arc(flipper.length,0,flipper.point,-Math.PI / 2,Math.PI /2)
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}


var W,H; // canvas width and height
// draws the flippers. This function would do all rendering of the
// game animations
function mainLoop(time){
    // resize if needed
    if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight){ // resize canvas if window size has changed
        W = canvas.width = innerWidth;
        H = canvas.height = innerHeight;
    }
    // clear canvas 
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // set default transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H); // clear the canvas
    // update flipper actions
    flipper.update();
    // render the flippers left and right
    drawFlipper(flipper.size * 2, H / 2, Math.PI * 0.25,-1);
    drawFlipper(W - flipper.size * 2, H / 2, Math.PI * 0.75,1);
    // get next animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
canvas {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    z-index : -10;
}
body {font-family : arial;}
```

```html
Press any key to move flippers. Move sliders to change flipper acction.<br>
Left slider is acceleration, right is drag. Some settings make them flip out, change setting and hit key to fix<br>
Accel<input id="accelIn" type="range" min = 0.01 max = 0.99 step = 0.01 value = 0.5></input>
Drag<input id="dragIn" type="range" min = 0.01 max = 0.99 step = 0.01 value = 0.5></input>
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now how do I handle collisions with a ball (more specific, handling the elastic angles between the ball and flipper on collision)

Comment: @sperfecto Good luck, Pinball is among the harder game writing challenges when learning to program. Well worth the endeavor.